# Insert repeated value across list slices

Tags: python

I have a list of booleans. I also have a list of start and end indices. In my list of booleans, I want each value to be `True` unless it lies in one of the slices defined in the list of indices. What I have written feels very clunky, any suggestions for making it nicer?

```
bools = [True] * 15
events = [(3, 5), (11, 16)]
for e in events:
    bools[e[0]:e[1]] = [False for x in range(*e)]
```

specifically, I don't like the `[False for x in range(*e)]` part. If I start messing around with the slices, the `range(*e)` starts to get messy, e.g.:

```
    bools[e[0]:e[1]+2] = [False for x in range(e[0], e[1]+2)]
```

What would be really nice is if there were a syntax to make every value in a list/slice take the same value, e.g.

```
    bools[e[0]:e[1]+2] = False
```

But this, obviously, is not correct syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interested in using numpy?

```
bools[e[0]:e[1]+2] = False
```

works in numpy.  You can also directly create your own [slice objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) which would let you do something like this

```
slices = [np.s_[3:6], np.s_[11:17]]
for s in slices:
    bools[s] = False
```

using s_ comes with full support for slicing syntax (step size, indexing from end of list, elipsis), not just enumerating a range

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import repeat
for e in events:
    bools[e[0]: e[1]] = repeat(False, e[1] - e[0])
```

Comment: Of course this only works if you avoid negative indices. But even that's pretty easy to fix by creating a `slice(e[0], e[1])` and calling its `indices(bools)` and then using that in place of `e[0]: e[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this:

```
events = [(3, 5), (11, 16)]
bools = [True] * 16
for start, end in events:
    for index in range(start, end):
        bools[index] = False
```